# What method can I use to interpolate a low frequency time series to a high frequency one, using the pattern from a higher resolution time series?

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series

I have a low temporal frequency irregular dataset with a value available every 40 to 48 days. I have another set of time-series data over the same period at 12 day frequency. The pattern of the two datasets are related (but not the values), and I'd like to use the pattern of the 12-day dataset to interpolate the 40-48 day data to a higher temporal resolution (e.g. daily or 10 days). I'll be implementing the analysis in Python (or R would be fine too), but I'm not sure of which method I should be looking to use. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you can use temporal disaggregation methods please see this article:
https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-2/sax-steiner.pdf

Comment: Nice answer. Could you provide more info from the link in your answer directly? this would help if the link expires

Comment: we have two kins of data high frequency(hf) and low frequency(lf).there are two mainly approach for increasing lf to hf. 1-according to another hf data 2-without care about another hf data.

Comment: We have two data types: high frequency (HF) and low frequency (LF). There are two main approaches to increase LF to HF: 1) regressing LF on HF (LF ~ HF) and 2) regressing LF solely on time (LF ~ t). The first method requires a close relationship with another HF dataset, while the second is independent of specific HF data. To illustrate, if GDP data is annual and you aim to make it high frequency, the ideal HF indicator for a close relationship would be the Consumer Price Index (CPI).

Comment: Better to add it to the answer than as a comment